# From which website clicks came?

Tags: google-analytics

Two days ago i published a new article on my website, [Racebooking.net](http://racebooking.net), and taking a look at Google Analytics, i found something amazing!!

I had 10 times more visitors than average on these 3 days. This means somebody shared my article on some website.

What i would love to know is:

1. On which website the article was shared. For instance, a user sees
   the link to my article posted to *somewebsite.com* -> the user clicks on the link -> the user
   arrives on my website. This way Google Analytics should be able to
   tell me that one user came from *somewebsite.com*, right?
2. If possible, the exact page on which
   the link was shared. For example, if it was shared on a forum, i
   wanna go to that page in order to "spy" comments and know what people think about my
   article

Is Google Analytics capable to do it? If not, how can i get what i want?
I really need to know these info to improve my website!

Thanks guys

Comment: Or, y'know, a few folks found your article through a Google Search.  Sharing didn't necessarily have to occur.

Comment: Yeah that's possible. But, if there is a way to know the clicks origin, i could know it. Again, is there a chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go to Acquisition > All Referrals to see an overview the websites that referred traffic to your site. Once you find a site you'd like to see more info on, click that site and you can see the exact page from which the referral came from.

[image]